# Mean Value Theorem on contraction of cosine on [0;1]

Tags: trigonometry, metric-spaces

I know that this kind of stuff has been asked before. But I try to be more specific. How can I use The mean value theorem to show that $$f(x)=\cos x$$ is a contraction on [0;1].
$$|\cos x-\cos y|<|2\times1\times\sin{\left(\dfrac{x-y}{2}\right)}|<|x-y|$$
What can I make of this result?

Comment: $|\sin x| \lt |x|$, except when $x=0$ in which case you have equality

Answer (score 3):

For $x,y \in[0,1]$

$|\cos x -\cos y| =|\sin \xi|*|x-y|$ with $ \xi \in [0,1]$

We have: $|\sin \xi| = \sin \xi \le \sin 1 <1$

Hence with $q:= \sin 1$ we have

$|\cos x -\cos y|  \le q*|x-y|$